# Can RegGetValue's lpSubKey be a non-direct descendant?

Tags: winapi, registry

Does the Windows API `RegGetValue` require a **direct descendant** for it's `lpSubKey` parameter?

Will this work?

```
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"ProductName",
            RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, outdata, &outdata_size);
```

**Edit:** I had a leading slash `\\` and Windows doesn't like it! Also converted UTF-8 strings to UTF-16 wide strings (Windows-Style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the Windows API `RegGetValue` require a **direct descendant** for it's `lpSubKey` parameter?

**No, it does not.**
You can specify a path just as you've shown. You also don't need the leading path separator (`\\`).

But the code you've shown may or may not work. Not because it specifies a path to the string, but because you're probably mixing Unicode and ANSI strings. From your user name (unixman), I assume that you're relatively new to Windows programming, so it's worth noting that Windows applications are entirely Unicode and have been for more than a decade. You should therefore always compile your code as Unicode and prefix string literals with `L` (to indicate a wide, or Unicode, string).

Likewise, make sure that `outdata` is declared as an array of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Unix apps are too, they just use UTF-8 which is alot like ASCII for American English ;) I am changing my question to use UTF-16 wide strings :).